# getting data from multiple tables in single query -mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I use these query to select user_ids of users who have similar selection of books read.

```
SELECT r2.user_id
FROM `read` r1
JOIN `read` r2
ON r1.user_id <> r2.user_id AND r1.book_id = r2.book_id
WHERE r1.user_id = 1
GROUP BY r2.user_id
HAVING count(*) >= 5
```

But I don't want to simply display user_id. But also data about this user_id from other tables!

Query above uses only this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `read` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `book_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `No duplicates` (`user_id`,`book_id`),
  KEY `book_id` (`book_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `connections_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `connections_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`) REFERENCES `books` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

But I also have:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` char(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` char(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `book` char(55) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `book` (`book`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `books_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So for every user_id in the list generated by my query, I want also to have `email` from `users`. And all book_ids from read for that user, but these book_ids are ids and I want that to show book from books based on book_ids.

Wow, will anyone understand what I wrote?

:L)

Comment: just join whatever tables you need also and select the desired columns from them

Comment: @wxyz just join is vague enough, I'm not very familiar with sql :) I'm reading though...

Comment: @wxyz where would I add another join?

Comment: @wxyz - horrible advice --> did you even look at his query?  It is based on a `HAVING` clause for logic.  You cannot just `JOIN`

Comment: @AgRizzo, since it's joining on foreign key, from child to master, no additional rows will be added

Comment: @wxyz - one of us doesn't understand what the OP wants.  His first query lists users that have at least 5 books in common (with user=1).  The requested solution needs to have the same users with their email (at this point no additional rows) Then the books they have in common, which will add at least 4 more rows per user - effectively increasing the size of the recordset by a minimum of 5x (at least according to what I understand)

Comment: @AgRizzo, sorry, you're right about the books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  Hopefully no syntax errors.  If it doesn't work, please go to SQLFiddle.com and load up some test data

```
SELECT users.id, users.email, book.books
FROM (
  SELECT r2.user_id
  FROM `read` r1
  JOIN `read` r2
    ON r1.user_id <> r2.user_id 
      AND r1.book_id = r2.book_id
  WHERE r1.user_id = 1
  GROUP BY r2.user_id
  HAVING count(*) >= 5) as t1
 JOIN users
   ON t1.user_id = users.id
 JOIN read
   ON read.user_id = t1.user_id
 JOIN books
   ON books.id = read.book_id
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * 
              FROM read 
              WHERE read.user_id = 1 
                AND read.book_id = book.id)
```

To summarize with a list - sorted by books in common descending:

```
SELECT users.id, users.email, t1.qty, GROUP_CONCAT(book.books)
FROM (
  SELECT r2.user_id, COUNT(*) AS qty
  FROM `read` r1
  JOIN `read` r2
    ON r1.user_id <> r2.user_id 
      AND r1.book_id = r2.book_id
  WHERE r1.user_id = 1
  GROUP BY r2.user_id
  HAVING count(*) >= 5) as t1
 JOIN users
   ON t1.user_id = users.id
 JOIN read
   ON read.user_id = t1.user_id
 JOIN books
   ON books.id = read.book_id
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * 
              FROM read 
              WHERE read.user_id = 1 
                AND read.book_id = book.id)
 GROUP BY users.id, users.email, t1.qty
 ORDER BY t1.qty DESC, users.email ASC
```

Comment: works like charm! I'm trying to learn these joins, but I need better docs, I cannot understand anything :D on the other hand, returned array contains duplicates I mean same user_id different word for each word they have in common. How would I combine these results? I simply need string of words they have in common. Should I do this in php? intreating over array and changing it?

Comment: p.s. is this query considered heavy? How well would it scale?

Comment: In terms of heavy, the query is not perfect because it goes back to the `read` table to get more information.  But I would not worry about it right now.  Worst case - this becomes a choke point, then build a temp/ cache table of the results of your first query and update the table every ... 1hr, 1 day, whatever

Comment: Again, works beautifully. Where did you learn so much about sql? And since you are the guru, I will ask you one last question :D if you are ok with this of course. Is it possible to order list according to how many books they have in common? so the list should start with the user with most matches...

Comment: I changed the 2nd query for your sort requirements. I brought the quantity of books in common from your first query (in which it was not explicitly listed) to the outer query.  Then I added it as a `SELECT` column, so that it was explicitly available in the `ORDER BY`. I like to have the `ORDER BY` columns in the `SELECT`. My other personal best practice when using a `GROUP BY`, I like to have every`SELECT` column either in the `GROUP BY` or an aggregate function.  While both of my best practices are not required in MySQL, I find it helps my readability and troubleshooting.

Comment: In terms of learning, mine came from experience (actually from failure - more failure than I would like to admit :) ). StackOverflow is an awesome resource to solve problems.  I find it even more valuable to read SO posts to understand how others have solved problems with better technique than I would have used.

Comment: Yes SO is fantastic, I try to help others too, the best way of learning is analysing problems of the other people :) I understood most of the query, but I don't get these parts: GROUP BY users.id, users.email, t1.qty
 ORDER BY t1.qty DESC, users.email ASC - why do I need users.email in those two lines?

Comment: You _"need"_ email in the GROUP BY because it is my best practice (see previous comment).  You don't need it the ORDER BY, but I tried to 2nd guess your next request :)

Comment: if I understood best practice, than I need to add GROUP_CONCAT(book.books) also right to group by? about the second section, hm, how can you order by 2 columns with different directions?

Comment: p.s. i really like how you indented the query :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40259/discussion-between-agrizzo-and-sandro-dzneladze)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    SELECT r2.user_id,u1.email,b1.books
    FROM `read` r1
    JOIN `read` r2
    ON r1.user_id <> r2.user_id AND r1.book_id = r2.book_id
    JOIN `users` u1
    ON r2.user_id =u1.id
    JOIN `books` b1
    ON r1.book_id=b1.id
    WHERE r1.user_id = 1
    GROUP BY r2.user_id
    HAVING count(*) >= 5
```

Comment: ON r2.user_id =u1.id instead of ON r1.user_id =u1.id otherwise it was returning only extra field email for the r1_user_id = 1.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze thanx mate..made changes